# Duplicate content with the same URL, google authorship

Tags: urls, homepage, recent-posts, google

I have recently added google authorship to my wordpress blog. When I search for specific posts on my blog, they come up with the post with my google+ picture and byline. On the other hand, when I search only for the title of my blog, I get my homepage (with google+ image and byline) and also a few post pages (this time without google+ picture, but with byline). The URL for these posts (with and without googe+ image) is exactly the same, and in any case I have already set my preferred canonical settings using my SEO plugin.

I think the problem is that my homepage shows recent posts (full excerpts), and then there is also my individual post pages with the same URL and same content. My guess is that the posts on my homepage are coming up in search results without the google+ picture (but with the author byline in search results). I am not sure how to resolve this issue, without changing the structure of my site. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not in how your site is coded or operated, but in how Google decides to show their search results. When the homepage is pulled up, sometimes they'll show recent posts below it, but often won't show your author information next to it, because the same author has already been shown above. So there's nothing that you can do to change this behaviour. It sounds like your authorship markup is set up correctly, which is about all you can do.